# How to correctly switch between branches in PHPStorm?

Tags: git, phpstorm

So the problem is, I've made a new branch: *myname/mysuperbranch*

And at the same time I have origin/master branch. And after I've made changes to my branch I checkout back to origin/master and it still has all my changes that I made inside of the *myname/mysuperbranch* branch.

How do I correctly switch between branches? For example:

1. I made some changes in my myname/myspuerbranch
2. Save this changes locally.
3. Switch to origin/master branch, and it should be clean, without any changes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have made changes and *commited* them? Or are they just staged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make changes and simply switch the branch you will have the see the same changes in the other branch. You actually have to commit them first so the changes are on the staging area.

> VCS > Git > Commit File...

Or even push it to a remote branch. After your changes are on the staging area the branch will differ from your master when you switch back. Of course the files have to be added to your working directory first. Normally PHPStorm will add newly created files automatically. Otherwise simply rightclick them.

> Git > + Add

Answer (score 1):

Horst Jahns gave the Git way response.

In PhpStorm, you can shelf your local changes in the version control, Local Changes tab by right clicking on the state, then "shelve changes", accept with a small comment.

> Version Control > Local Changes > Right click on your changes > Shelve changes

This store the local modifications into PhpStorm and remove them from your current branch. You can now switch branch without conflict and work on the other one.

> VCS > Branches > YourBranch > Checkout

Once you finish with the other branch you can git commit or doing the same process of shelving.

When you changed branch, unshelve changes by right clicking on the shelf in the "Shelf" tab.

> Version Control > Shelf > Right click on the shelf you want > Unshelve (you can set it as active)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know of this useful feature!